# UISearchController UITextField background not showing white after update to iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

after the new update, I've noticed that my `UISearchController` isn't acting like it did before.

First, the `UITextField` no longer has a white background. I was trying to figure out why this is happening, but have had no luck. This is how I'm creating it.

[image]

```
var resultsSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

self.resultsSearchController.delegate = self
let searchBar = self.resultsSearchController.searchBar

self.resultsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.resultsSearchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.resultsSearchController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
searchBar.placeholder = "Catalog Search"
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.darkAqua
```

As best I can tell, the default `UITextField` default appearance seems to have changed is my guess.

Just wondering how to change it back, if possible.

***---EDIT---***
I attempted to do as suggested and added this code to `viewDidLoad()`

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.light
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

as well as adding this to the `UISearchController` code

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    self.resultsSearchController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.light
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

No combination of both of those codes was able to change it so that that `UITextField` presented as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I'm dumb. Its much easier that I was trying to make it for myself.
All I ended up doing was accessing the `UITextField` in the searchBar for the `UISearchController`

Adding this:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

With the code I already had seems to make it look normal again.